# Meteor.js return innerHTML in helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

is there any way I can return innerHTML in helper?
I mean something like this:

```
text: function(){
return "<p>It's working!</p>"
}
```

There would be more of those records since I loop them through {{#each}} loop and I tried to do it throught JQuery but had hard times naming classes/ID's so I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to do it with helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Handlebars.SafeString:

```
text: function(){
  return new Handlebars.SafeString("<p>It's working!</p>");
}
```

It will produce safe HTML string. Using not escaping with tripple brackets {{{...}}} is not secure if your helper returns something from user's input.

**EDIT:** in Meteor 1.* use Spacebars instead of Handlebars:

```
text: function(){
  return new Spacebars.SafeString("<p>It's working!</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can, just remember to call that helper with `{{{...}}}` instead of `{{...}}` so that it's not escaped:

```
{{#each paragraphs}}
  {{{text}}}
{{/each}}
```